# Powershell: Disable-ADAccount : The server is unwilling to process the request

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm working on a script to help disable accounts. I'm trying to get past this error:

```
Disable-ADAccount : The server is unwilling to process the request
At line:1 char:88
+ ... ad Steve"' -SearchBase "" -Server 10.10.2.225:3268 | Disable-ADAccount
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CN=Brad Steve...DC=lando,DC=com:ADUser) [Disable-ADAccount], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8245,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.DisableADAccount
```

Here is the code:

`Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "Brad Steve"' -SearchBase "" -Server 10.10.2.225:3268 | Disable-ADAccount`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this by trying to disable my domain admin account with a lesser privileged account.  I think this is because the account you are trying to disable is privileged (maybe a domain admin or something) and the account you are using to disable it doesn't have permission to do so.

There is an attribute called adminCount you can look at with something like:

```
Get-ADUser <UserName -Properties adminCount | fl
```

If adminCount is 1 AD will think it's a privileged account regardless of the actual privileges.  There is a process under the hood (SDPROP) in AD that protects highly privileged accounts by and enforced copying the ACL from the AdminSDHolder container.  adminCount will usually remain 1 even if the account is removed from the privileged group.

Of course if the account really is privileged then you're getting the error as you should.

Is there a reason you are going after the GC? I'd usually target the PDC Emulator for this sort of thing.